# How can I display zero-value records in a text box control?

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is probably a beginner question and I am missing something fundamental, but I appreciate anyone's time and effort.

I have inherited an Access database, where the data is kept in a separate file to the forms and reports.

A report is used to create a letter to summarise a set of results.

The relevant part is in the Detail section of the report, where pairs of Text Box controls are used to show the name of the test, and the result.

The behaviour of the text boxes is that they are hidden (including the name of the test) when the value is zero in the database. However, sometimes we need to include a zero value.

**Is this default behaviour?**

I have inspected the VBA project and cannot find any logic that is hiding the text boxes.

Other information:

- The field is set up as Number (double)
- The default value for the field has been made empty, not 0 which seems to be the default.
- I have tried using the format property for the control using #;#;0;"" as described here (http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21525364/Show-zero-values-as-dashes-on-an-Access-report.html)
- I have also tried using `ControlSource =IIF([fieldvalue]>0,[fieldvalue],"0")` which did show a zero, but the descriptor text box still disappeared, and it was appearing as 0 whether the database field value was 0 or nothing.

Please let me know of any other details that would be helpful.

Comment: No, there is no *default behavior* that hides text boxes when tests return zero. The issue is in the report itself, or the rows are being excluded in a condition in the underlying query. You'll need to look harder.

Comment: In addition to the query and the report VBA, check also the **Conditional format** of the textboxes.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.. seems clear and you told us what you'd tried, so have a +1 to equal that out. As @Andre stated, it sounds like whoever set this up might have wrote some VBA or a macro to get this behaviour. Check whether the report has these. Best way would be to open the report up in design view, open the property sheet (F4) and then go to the Events tab and check if any of the events listed have `[Event Procedure]` next to them; you can click the [...] button on any that do and check if any references are being made to your textboxes. (Let us know if you find anything)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.

I hadn't traced back for enough in the logic chain, which @KenWhite's answer gave me the hint for.

The issue was in the query underlying the report - the logic for the field had conditional parameters on it, using `IIf()` and `NULL` / `0` checks.